# ASP.NET web application not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Regards.

I have noticed that ASP.NET web application is not working in IE10.
Grid items are not click-able and several other jscript features do not work.

I have been digging into this and i found out that ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack. Now before i start digging into the problem and searching for available solutions I would like to hear some ideas of fixing the problem.

Let me say that the application is deployed in several dozens of servers and that it works in all browsers except IE10. If clients enable IE9 mode the application works, but still with some strange glitches.

I would like to know how is this fixable in some easy painless way?

With kind regards, no9

EDIT: I have included the AppBrowsersUpdate via NuGet package manager and deployed the application. But now I am getting this:

[image]

EDIT2: I have excluded "firefox.browser" from the application. Now the app works, its jst that in IE i am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well temporary I have resolved the issue like this (for anyone needing quick fix this should work), but the downfall is that every single client has to do it.

I have enabled compatibility mode in IE10 (ALT, Compatibility settings, add site).
This way the browser is running in IE9 compatibility mode.

For the document mode I added this code to my web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

It works for now, but I still urge anyone that might know the correct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott wrote good article about it awhile ago.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

In a nutshell there are two ways to fix the issue:

1. Update all your ASP.NET web apps with appropriate version of the [App_BrowsersUpdate](http://nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate) NuGet package which is designed to solve this issue.
2. Update all machines that use your web site with the following KBs

   1. .NET 4 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088
   2. .NET 2.0 -
      http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... i would need to update all the projects by simply just adding the package and re-deploying web application?

Comment: Yes, it should fix the issue.

Comment: I have tried including the fix in my web application. All went well, I have deployed the app. But now I am getting: Configuration Error: Parser Error Message: The browser or gateway element with ID 'Firefox' cannot be found. Any tips?

Comment: I have edited my original question that now contains problems I am facing with App_BrowsersUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Hotfix for IE10 issues

.Net 4 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)
.Net 2 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565)

You can get references from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/790ca046-73c4-4b0c-8e0d-1db5190c988b

Its help me lot to solve IE10 issues.